# What cache to use in Spring boot application to avoid redundant database calls?

Tags: mysql, spring, database

I am designing a pastebin kind of application. Someone can login to the website and enter some texts and he gets a URL. Anyone with this URL can access the text which was entered before. For example, https://pastebin.com/eWCfCck1 . Opening this URL

I have created a page called **Past Edit History** so that anyone can see all their previously stored texts. I am using a Spring boot backend which calls a Database query on MYSQL and fetches a list of previously stored text for a user.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/pastEditHistory")
public String user(Principal principal, Model model, HttpSession httpSession){
    //Fetch the email of this user
    LinkedHashMap<Object,Object> map = (LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>)
            ((OAuth2Authentication) principal).getUserAuthentication().getDetails();
    String emailId = (String) map.get("email");
    
    //Find all the past stored texts for this user. Each PastedNote has the text and URL of the page
    List<PastedNote> pasteNotes = pastebinRepository.findByAccountIdOrderByTimestampDesc(emailId);
    //Storing in model to be viewed (rendered) on the frontend HTML
    model.addAttribute("pasteNotes",pasteNotes);
    // Http Session storing 
    httpSession.setAttribute("tier",accountInfo.getTier());
    return "editHistory";
}
```

1. Every refresh on this page would be a **database** call (which could take some time). Is it possible to get a **trigger** from the database if any new information is inserted and then only make the DB call?
2. Suppose there are no new updates on the database and I know that for this account, this texts will remain the same. Is storing in httpsession a good option and using it as a temporary store a good option? (So that if I go to some other page and come back to **Past Edit History** page, I can load from **HttpSession** instead of making the database call?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is Hibernate's `second-level-cache`:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
```